# Call PHP function from Javascript - PHP in separate file

Tags: php, javascript, function, variables

I am having trouble populating a Javascript variable from PHP.

My index.php file is in typical form i.e.

```
 <?php
  function blah () {}
  function doThis ($sUserID) {}
 ?>

 <HTML>
   <head>
     <script src="test.js"></script>  
   </head>

   show results
 </HTML>
```

Trouble is I need to populate a Javascript variable (in the 'test.js' file) with a value called from a PHP function (which is in the php file).

I have tried:

```
    var jsVar = '<?php echo doThis(sUserID)?>';
document.write("jsVar: ", jsVar);
```

But no result.

So how do I call the PHP function (in another PHP file) from test.js?

Thanks.

Comment: 65% isn't the worse I've seen, but indeed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a global variable before `test.js` gets loaded, that should work

```
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript>
       var jsVar = '<?php echo doThis(sUserID) ?>';
     </script>
     <script src="test.js"></script>  
   </head>
```

If the `doThis(sUserID);` returns a valid string, it should work.

Comment: Hi dbf:  Good idea but I need to run a Javascript function first to get the sUserID variable, which I then pass to the PHP, which in turn passes back data.

Comment: @Jeremy well to be honest, I think you have to rethink your logic design here.

Comment: You're right.  I placed all the Javascript in the <head> section rather than a separate .js file.  Works fine.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You `doThis()` does not return anything so `echo` will show nothing. But it is not all. You cannot call PHP function from JS script, unless you make JS file to be passed thru PHP interpreter first (which is NOT default behaviour). You could do the trick by renaming your `test.js` into `test.php`

Comment: Thanks.  I did try this, but having a PHP file containing all my Javascript code seems to confuse the Eclipse editor.